# Cannot execute Virsh command through SSH on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 for KVM host. On a jumphost, I tried to execute virsh command:

> ssh user@ip "virsh dominfo vm1"

I got an error: failed to get domain 'vm1'
But this command worked well on KVM host.
I figured out that this problem does not happen if the KVM host is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The VM that name must exist. Use the correct name.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, the VM has existed. I even use domain ID but still got the same issue

Comment: FYI: reported in [LP bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1787800)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default URI of virsh to connect to can change (and it did change upstream).

You can check that with:

```
$ ssh ubuntu@ip -t 'bash -l -c "virsh uri"'
qemu:///system
$ ssh ubuntu@ip "virsh uri"
qemu:///session
```

Ubuntu tries to help with an environment variable `LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI=qemu:///system` but that is only available in login shells.

So you'd either need to make sure you use full login shells e.g.:

```
  $ ssh ubuntu@ip -t 'bash -l -c "virsh dominfo vm1"'
```

Or to augment your call with the env var on your own:

```
  $ ssh ubuntu@ip "LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI=qemu:///system virsh dominfo vm1"
```

Comment: I was hit by this change in behavior recently and could not figure out what is happening, this explains it, thank you.